# Attribute Error while trying to make a list out of async function

Tags: python, list, fastapi

I am trying to make a list from the async function in python and cannot seem to get it done.
I get the `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dict'`. I believe my approach is wrong. Please can someone point me in the write direction?

```
    async def order_id_product(self, order_id: int, aos: Optional[list[dict]]):
        if aos:
            for a in aos:
                product_res = await self._session.execute(select(Product).where(Product.id == a.product_id))
                product = product_res.scalars().first()
                order_product_result = await self._session.execute(insert(OrderProduct)
                                                                   .values(order_id=order_id, product_id=product.id, vendor_id=product.vendor_id, quantity=a.quantity).returning(OrderProduct))
                await self._session.commit()
                return order_product_result.first()
```

I want to iterate through this function to return the below list.

```
@routers.post('/', status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
async def order(aos: Optional[list[OrderPSchema]], order_id: int,  db: AsyncSession = Depends(get_db)):
    return await OrderRepository(session=db)).order_id_product(aos=aos, order_id=order_id)
```

The schema is below:

```
class OrderPSchema(BaseModel):
    product_id: int
    quantity: int

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

What i want to achieve is a list of the above schema.

```
[
  {
    "product_id": 0,
    "quantity": 0
  },
  {
    "product_id": 0,
    "quantity": 0
  },
  {
    "product_id": 0,
    "quantity": 0
  }
]
```

Is my approach useless as i am starting to believe or is this acually possible

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined a `response_model` for your controller, so FastAPI has no idea how to convert a list of SQLAlchemy objects to a JSON response.

```py
@routers.post('/', response_model=List[OrderPSchema], status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @matslindh With the ```response_model``` i get a seperate error `value is not a valid list (type=type_error.list)`

Comment: I was able to use the response model by changing `return order_product_result.first()` to `return order_product_result.all()` but still getting only back only one item from the list instead of the whole list.

Comment: @pythoneke you're returning inside your `for` loop, so you only insert one row. Instead you'll have to keep all the returned entries in a list, and then return _after_ the `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks @matsLindh it works now. I was returning inside the forr loop like you said. Although i had to create an empty list `res = []` and append the empty list to the result. `res.append(final_result[0:])` then i returned `return res`